# What is the name of this specific QWERTY keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, qwerty

I'm talking about the QWERTY keyboard layout which has the big L-shaped <kbd>Enter</kbd>  key and the backward slash key placed left of the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

[image: Image of a keyboard with the described keyboard layout]

Comment: Looks like a modified Windows United States keyboard layout.  Normally the bottom of the enter key is narrowed and the  `"\"` key is placed there but I see they have narrowed the `shift` key instead to make room for it.  Can you provide the manufacturer and model?  Can you provide a full shot?  Most qwerty layout variants that are named  are tied to languages and locals.

Comment: The keyboard is Zowie Celeritas II, more picture on their website, but no information about the layout unfortunately, hence my problem.
https://zowie.benq.com/en-ap/keyboard/celeritas-ii.html

Answer (score -1):

As described in [Wikipedia](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Return_key#Backwards_L-shaped):

"A "backwards-L shaped" (or just "L-shaped") Return key is the union of the ISO and ANSI Return keys. The key is often called Big-ass Enter because of its size, or Asian enter because it is found on many East Asian keyboards.

There have been studies that have shown it to be easier to hit accurately than the ISO and ANSI Return keys."